# Windows ALT+NUMPAD ASCII Key Combos

Tags: windows, keyboard, ascii

You all probably know about Windows' ability to render any character by specifying it's ASCII code using the numpad. To do so, you press and hold the <kbd>Alt</kbd> key while sequentially pressing the numbers that make up the ASCII code on the numpad. So if I press and hold <kbd>Alt</kbd>, then I press <kbd>1</kbd> then <kbd>2</kbd> on the numpad and release <kbd>Alt</kbd>, I get male sign (♀).

My question is, what is the defined behaviour for pressing more than one keys at the same time? Because if I try the same thing but instead press <kbd>1</kbd> and <kbd>2</kbd> at the same time instead of sequentially, I get a section sign (§). What's up with that?

Comment: Apparently does are called Alt codes. Here's the Wikipedia article, although it isn't very useful and would require cleanup http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Windows_Alt_keycodes

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are probably hitting the combination in the wrong order when you hit <kbd>1</kbd>+<kbd>2</kbd> at the same time. It may seem like you hit the two number keys at the same time *but* really you are hitting one number before the other.

<kbd>Alt</kbd> + <kbd>2</kbd>, <kbd>1</kbd>... **is `§`**
<kbd>Alt</kbd> + <kbd>1</kbd>, <kbd>2</kbd>... **is `♀`**

Comment: How didn't I catch that. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

You're actually entering Alt-2-1: §. ♀ is the result of Alt-1-2. So nothing's happening because you press them together, the computer's interpreting it as single keypresses in whatever order the keyboard sends them (which happens to be 2-1, probably because of how you type). Also, note that the Alt code system isn't ASCII, instead it allows you to enter Unicode characters (of which there are far more).